# iMacros from my PHP script under Linux

Tags: php, linux, console, imacros

I've made a macro and got it to work correctly. So far, I can play the macro from my PHP script with the command line:

```
exec('firefox  http://run.imacros.net/?m=my_macro.iim');
```

Now I would like to improve my program by using the scripting interface. I've read on the documentation that I need the COM class, which is not available on the Linux versions of PHP. So do you have an idea of how I can use PHP to run my scripts. Actually I don't want Firefox to show up everytime I launch the script, so what I really want is a way to "hide" it.

Thanks.

Comment: it extracts data from a website

Comment: perhaps you should be doing that with php (and permission from the site owner)

Comment: I tried but failed. The website is made with the seam framework.